# Python - How to make crosstable in pandas from non numeric data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, data-science

So, the thing is I need to create a crosstable from string data. I mean like in excel, if You put some string data into crosstable it is going to be automatically transformed into counted values per the other factor. For instance, I have column 'A' which contains application numbers and column 'B' which contains dates. I need to show how many applications were placed per each day. Classic crosstable returns me an error.

```
data.columns = [['applicationnumber', 'date', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3']] #mostly string values
```

Examples of input data: 
applicationnumber = "AAA12345678"
date = 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: how do you think we can help if you dont give us any input data?

Comment: Are you trying to create a pivot table? check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: That's the spirit

Comment: you can use `select_dtypes` and then crosstab or pivot table. as luigigi has said, it's imperative to provide test data for your use case, 5-10 rows and your expected output. remember you're talking to strangers who have no idea what you're thinking, the only interaction we have is 4 sentences above and 0 test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['app1', '01/01/2019'],
                   ['app2', '01/02/2019'],
                   ['app3', '01/02/2019'],
                   ['app4', '01/02/2019'],
                   ['app5', '01/04/2019'],
                   ['app6', '01/04/2019']],
                  columns=['app.no','date'])

print(pd.pivot_table(df, values='app.no', index='date', aggfunc=np.size))
```

Output:

```
            app.no
date              
01/01/2019       1
01/02/2019       3
01/04/2019       2
```